# How to transform an array with several bytes inside into its translation in int?

Tags: java, arrays, binary, concatenation

Given an array filled with 4 bytes inside (R,G,B,A), I'm trying to translate this array full of 4 8bits numbers into its translation in 32bits. To be more clear, if I get an array such as:

```
byte[] tab = {1,2,3,4};
```

with translated in binary in 8bit :

```
1 = 0b00000001
2 = 0b00000010
3 = 0b00000011
4 = 0b00000100
```

Then, my method should return a byte array such as :

```
newTab = {00000001_00000010_00000011_00000100};
```

For some reason, I'm trying to do this without using a String to concatenate the bytes.

I've already tried something with binary operators such as <<, >> or |, but without success...

So far, my code looks like this :

```
byte[] tab = {1,2,3,4};
int tmp,tabToInt = 0;
for (int x = 0 ; x < tab.length ; ++x){
tmp = tmp << (tab.length - 1 - x)*8;
byteToInt = byteToInt | tmp;
}
return tabToInt;
```

But it didn't seem to work, even less with negatives bytes... (like `-1 = 0b11111111`)

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: How exactly is it not working? What result do you get?

Comment: What type is `newTab = {00000001_00000010_00000011_00000100};`?

Comment: For exemple, with the byte [ ] array {0,-68,97,78}, i get -4431538 insted of 12345678...

Comment: And the newTab is here just to show the translation in binary, my method should return the int translation of {00000001_00000010_00000011_00000100}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ByteBuffer` like this.

```
byte[] tab = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int tabToInt = ByteBuffer.wrap(tab).getInt();
System.out.println("decimal = " + tabToInt);
System.out.println("binary = " + Integer.toBinaryString(tabToInt));
System.out.println("hexadecimal =" + Integer.toHexString(tabToInt));
```

output

```
decimal = 16909060
binary = 1000000100000001100000100
hexadecimal =1020304
```

Answer (score 0):

`ByteBuffer` can do it, but only if you get passed at least 4 bytes.

The problem with your code is two-fold:

- I think you typoed somewhere, your code doesn't even compile. I think you meant `tmp = tab[x] << (tab.length - 1 - x)*8;`. Your snippet never does anything with `tab` other than ask for its length.
- Negative numbers extend, and java will convert any byte or short to an `int` the moment you do any math to it. So, `0b1111 1111`, if you try to do e.g. `<< 8` on that, java first turns that -1 byte into a -1 int (so that's now **32** 1 bits), and then dutifully left shifts it by 8, so now that's 24 1 bits, followed by 8 0 bits. You then bitwise OR that into your target, and thus now the target is mostly 1 bits. To convert a byte to an int **without** "sign extension", `(b & 0xFF` does it:

```java
byte b = (byte) 0b1111_1111;
assert b == -1; // yup, it is
int c = b; // legal
assert c == -1; // yeah, still is. uhoh. That's...
int d = 0b11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111;
assert c == d; // yeah. We don't want that.
int e = (b & 0xFF);
assert e = 255;
int f = 0b0000000_0000000_0000000_11111111;
assert e == f; // yes!
```

Comment: Okay right, thank you, i understand better how the bytes work in java